# Restrict private proxy server (Squid) to only self-written client

Tags: c#, proxy, client-server, squid, restriction

I use squid as proxy server and I written a program in C# for clients that use that proxy server for internet communication.

What I want is:

- Only my own client program be able to use proxy server (squid)
- Squid or something else on the server deny other programs' connection request

Do I need to write another program to do that job on the server?
What is your suggestion?

Comment: use the firewall to deny everything except squid then have your app use squid.

Comment: excuse me may did not imply my question. i'd like only my program written by C# can communicate with squid. not other program on client.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set it up to [ask a password](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_%3a_Ch32_%3a_Controlling_Web_Access_with_Squid#Password_Authentication_Using_NCSA)?

Comment: can i do that for all user in code? or user must do it for each request manualy?

Comment: @Mostafa Shaeri - Yes, your program can specify the username/password in code.